# Close Tooltip on Body Click Event - not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I've got this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/u8t77p75/

I want to achieve that, when I click on "body" the js will check if actual a tip is visible and if so hide this.

I wanted to try something like:

```js
if ($tooltipContainer.hasClass('active')) {
 $('body').click(function() {
      $tipLink.triggerHandler('click');
 });
}
```

It works but not perfectly. When I insert this snippet, it calls the trigger, but I need to click several times to open or close. I think it's because the whole click-function get's invoked. Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a click handler to the document that checks if you have clicked outside of your tooltip and that there is one open. The code is like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).not(':has(.lhde__tooltip)').length == 0 && $('div.opened').length) {
        // current click target is not the tooltip and a tip is open
        $('div.opened').remove();
    }
});
```

Your code works but I would have a look at [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) from bootstrap because it's easier to create popovers. See a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/nyc3mc67/)

Please find your code below and here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/43v23mtb/).

```js
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var $tipLink = $('.lhde__tooltip'),
        $tipContent = $('.lhde__tooltip__content');

    //initial hide tipContent
    $tipContent.hide();

    $tipLink.click(function (e) {
        // prevent click event
        e.preventDefault();

        var $clicked = $(this),
            href = $(this).attr('href'),
            $tooltipContainer = $(href);

        // if a container with the id was found
        if ($tooltipContainer.length) {

            // if the tooltip is not already active
            if (!$tooltipContainer.hasClass('active')) {

                $tipContent.removeClass('active');
                $('.lhde__tooltip__content.opened').remove();

                $tooltipContainer.addClass('active');
                $clicked.append('<div class="lhde__tooltip__content opened">' + $tooltipContainer.html() + '</div>');

                // hide the tooltip
            } else {
                $tipContent.removeClass('active');
                $('.lhde__tooltip__content.opened').remove();
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).not(':has(.lhde__tooltip)').length == 0 && $('div.opened').length) {
            // current click target is not the tooltip and a tip is open
            //console.log($('div.opened'));
            $('div.opened').remove();
            //$tipContent.removeClass('active');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.content {
    width: 150px;
    background: #eee;
    color: #333;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.lhde__tooltip__content {
    position: absolute;
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"> <a class="lhde__tooltip" href="#kardiologen">Kardiologen</a>
 <a class="lhde__tooltip" href="#pneumologen">Pneumologen</a>

</div>
<div class="lhde__tooltip__content" id="kardiologen">
     <h3 class="lhde__third-headline">Kardiologen</h3>

    <p class="lhde__paragraph">Lorem ipsum dollor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum soccis natoque penatabus et magais dis partiruent.</p> <span class="lhde__icon lhde__icon--close"></span>

</div>
<div class="lhde__tooltip__content" id="pneumologen">
     <h3 class="lhde__third-headline">Pneumologen</h3>

    <p class="lhde__paragraph">Lorem ipsum dollor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum soccis natoque penatabus et magais dis partiruent.</p> <span class="lhde__icon lhde__icon--close"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The Snipped provided works like a charm :)

Yeah I'd use a framework like bootstrap or foundation, but I have no permission to do that within my project :)